# Chaining arrows of types `a b [c]` and `a c d`

Tags: haskell, arrows

I have an arrow which outputs a list of values (`a b [c]`) and another arrow which accepts a single value of that type (`a c d`). What I need basically is a way to chain them or uplift the second arrow to `a [c] [d]`.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with just `Arrow`. You probably either need `ArrowApply` or some lifting function specific to whatever type of arrows you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this with just `Arrow` type class. Lifting `a b c` into `a [b] [c]` requires choice between `[]` and `(:)` case. Luckily for us, `ArrowChoice` offers exactly this operation.

```
mapA :: ArrowChoice a => a b c -> a [b] [c]
mapA f = proc list -> case list of
    []   -> returnA -< []
    x:xs -> do
        y  <- f      -< x
        ys <- mapA f -< xs
        returnA      -< y:ys
```

Your function is then simply:

```
chain :: ArrowChoice a => a b [c] -> a c d -> a b [d]
chain f g = f >>> mapA g
```

---

Without `proc` notation, we would need a function that translates list constructors into `Either`:

```
listCase :: [a] -> Either () (a, [a])
listCase []     = Left ()
listCase (x:xs) = Right (x,xs)

mapA f = arr listCase >>>
    arr (const []) ||| (f *** mapA f >>> arr (uncurry (:)))
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you. I'll get to testing it.

Comment: Just found this solution in ["Programming with Arrows"](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~rjmh/afp-arrows.pdf) by John Hughes

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: Ah yes, I remember reading that paper. That's where most of my arrow knowledge comes from.